# How to write a document using NotesTex package?

Tags: documentclass

I would like to write a document using NotesTex. However, after downloading it, I don’t know how to write a document using that template, i.e. do I have to use any command in a new file or do I have to use the files inside the downloadable folder?

Comment: As a starter, the NotesTeX reader on github provides a simple example https://github.com/Adhumunt/NotesTeX/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 2):

1. You have to put the file `NotesTeX.sty` where TeX can find it. Your working directory is a good place. If you have a recent installation of MiKTeX or TeXLive, you don't have to do anything at all, it is already there.
2. You have to load the NotesTeX package, with `\usepackage{NotesTeX}`
3. You can go ahead now and use everything detailed in the [`NotesTeX  documentation`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/notestex/doc/NotesTeX.pdf)

You could start with this snippet:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{NotesTeX}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{libertine}

\title{Title\\Subtitle}
\author{Author}
\affiliation{Affiliation}
\emailAdd{author@affiliation.edu}


\begin{document}
    \maketitle

    \section{Not Kant}
    A sidenote.\sn{Hello, here!}

    \section{Kant}
    \kant[1]

    \section{Again: not Kant}
    A marginnote.\mn{Hi, there!}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. However, despite having a recent version of TeXLive, the package is not included and I can't still use the package.

Comment: Do you have a full installation of TL2018? Try: `tlmgr info notestex` for information and `tlmgr install notestex` for installation. Depending on your OS you might have to use `sudo`.

Comment: @user157226 Also, if you have problems using `tlmgr`, you can always just download [`NotesTeX.sty`](https://github.com/Adhumunt/NotesTeX/blob/master/NoTeX/NotesTeX.sty) and save it in your working directory, i.e. the place where your `.tex` file is.

Comment: Hello @DG', thank you for helping with this issue!

Comment: @Aditya Glad to help. Btw: Nice package you have there (sorry).